# Why can´t I see complete name in SSMS result list?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

In result tab in SSMS I cannot see whole column name, part of name gets replaced by dots (...), is this a setting or something?

[image: Dots in SSMS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know there is no way to change the width of result set because it generated at runtime.
You  can ask for this feature from [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/sqlserver/)

I know it has been asked before but closed.